# Mocking base interface properties does not work through a mock of a derived interface

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have these interfaces:

```cs
public interface IBase
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    new int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The following test works correctly:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDerived>( MockBehavior.Strict );
mock.SetupGet( m => m.Value ).Returns( 0 );

IDerived o = mock.Object;

Assert.That( o.Value, Is.EqualTo( 0 ) );
```

However, when I change the type of `o` to `IBase`, I get the following error:

```
Message: Moq.MockException : IBase.Value invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.
```

Is that by design? Do I need to remove the `Strict` flag in order to access the base interface property (which is hidden by the derived interface)? Or is there some other kind of setup which I could use?

As a side note, there was an [issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/275) dealing with the base/derived read-only/read-write properties but the declared type of the mock object was not considered there. Could this be another issue in Moq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Value` property of `IBase` interface and `IDerived` interface are not the same. For example you can do this:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    new string Value { get; }
}

public class Implementation : IDerived
{
    string IBase.Value { get; } = "Base";

    string IDerived.Value { get; } = "Derived";
}
```

To mock the `IDerived` interface correctly, you should setup return value for both properties. `Mock.As` method is useful here to cast `IDerived` interface to `IBase`.

```
Mock<IDerived> mock = new Mock<IDerived>( MockBehavior.Strict );
mock.Setup( obj => obj.Value ).Returns( "Derived" );
mock.As<IBase>().Setup( obj => obj.Value ).Returns( "Base" );
```